# How to use Oracle sequence with Hibernate + Spring

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, sequence

Inside my entity class

```
     package com.entity;
// Generated May 23, 2015 10:43:49 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * EmpTest generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="EMP_TEST"
    ,schema="SCOTT"
)
public class EmpTest  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private BigDecimal id;
     private String ename;
     private Date dob;
     private BigDecimal sal;

    public EmpTest() {
    }

    public EmpTest(BigDecimal id, String ename, Date dob, BigDecimal sal) {
       this.id = id;
       this.ename = ename;
       this.dob = dob;
       this.sal = sal;
    }

     @Id 

     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "test_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "test_seq",
            sequenceName = "TEST_SEQ" , allocationSize=1)  
    @Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22, scale=0)
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="ENAME", nullable=false, length=50)
    public String getEname() {
        return this.ename;
    }

    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DOB", nullable=false, length=7)
    public Date getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }


    @Column(name="SAL", nullable=false, precision=5)
    public BigDecimal getSal() {
        return this.sal;
    }

    public void setSal(BigDecimal sal) {
        this.sal = sal;
    }




}
```

`TEST_SEQ` is the sequence, which I created under my schema. But, when I'm trying to add record then getting following exception

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID1_0_0_, this_.ENAME as ENAME2_0_0_, this_.DOB as DOB3_0_0_, this_.SAL as SAL4_0_0_ from SCOTT.EMP_TEST this_
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy318.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.model.EmpModelImp.add(EmpModelImp.java:32)
    at com.model.EmpServiceImpl.add(EmpServiceImpl.java:27)
    at com.controller.EmpControl.doActions(EmpControl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 62 more
```

I have noticed that, It is trying to get next value from `hibernate_sequence` sequence, which doesn't exist in my database. On the other hand in my entity class I have pointed to `TEST_SEQ`, which exist in my database. I don't why It trying to get next sequence value from `hibernate_sequence`. Anyone please help me on this ?

**==Update==**

**EmpTest.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entity.EmpTest" table="EMP_TEST" schema="SCOTT" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence" />
        </id>
        <property name="ename" type="string">
            <column name="ENAME" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="DOB" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="sal" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="SAL" precision="5" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Add function insert record into table

```
 public void add(EmpTest emp) {
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            System.out.println(emp.getEname()+" "+emp.getDob());
            session.save(emp);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: İf sequence not exists database of course you get exception

Comment: It is there.. I have created myself.

Comment: Do you post full stacktrace?

Comment: yes.. It was full stacktrace.

Comment: Try referencing the schema in the sequenceName: `@SequenceGenerator(name = "test_seq", sequenceName = "YOUR_SCHEMA.TEST_SEQ" , allocationSize=1) ` and replace "YOUR_SCHEMA" with whatever your actual schema is.

Comment: Also, do you have any .hbm mapping files in your project? This came up recently with a coworker where they thought they were using the JPA annotations, but there was still a .hbm mapping file that was being loaded and giving the wrong sequence information.

Comment: Are you sure you have rebuilt the project since adding the annotations, and running with the up-to-date classes? Why are you using aBigDecimal instead of a simple Long? Could you post the complete entity and the code used to test the insertion? Maybe you're trying to insert another entity.

Comment: I have updated my post with full code. Please let me know, in case anything missing

Comment: The `EmpTest.hbm.xml` is your problem. You either need to correct your `EmpTest.hbm.xml` and not use annotations or remove the mapping file and only use the annotations.

Comment: Ok.. So, Is `EmpTest.hbm.xml` file fine or anything needed to correct. I will use `xml` file, please suggest what correction needed.

Comment: did you try `SCOTT.TEST_SEQ` as well check its working or not `SELECT SCOTT.TEST_SEQ.nextval FROM dual;`

Comment: `SELECT SCOTT.TEST_SEQ.nextval FROM dual;` is working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EmpTest.hbm.xml mapping file does not reference your sequence. Try changing it to the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.entity.EmpTest" table="EMP_TEST" schema="SCOTT" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">TEST_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="ename" type="string">
            <column name="ENAME" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="DOB" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="sal" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="SAL" precision="5" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```